# C++ bool behaviours not as expected

Tags: c++, string-comparison, c-strings, boolean-logic

I have some strange problem with reversed boolean value in C++. :')
I want to check if argument passed to main method is not "file.txt". When it's not I want to create new file with name given as main argument and write there lines of randomized data. Otherwise I want to read data from "file.txt".
Everything works just fine as I wished, but when I type
`g++ sourcefile.cpp header.h` in terminal, and then
`./a.out file.txt` 
Program is entering this random data into "file.txt" instead of reading from it.
And on the other hand when I type:
`./a.out someRandomData.txt` it is reading from "file.txt". Any ideas?

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        if(argv[1] != "file.txt"){
            fileWithRandomData(argv[1]);    
        }
        else{

        std::vector<std::string> row;
        std::string line, word, temp;
        std::ifstream MyReadFile(argv[1]);
        (...)
```

And here is sample of my fileWithRandomData funtion:

```
     void fileWithRandomData(string name){
        srand(time(NULL));
       
        std::ofstream MyFile(name);
        int metalsNumber = rand() % 5000 + 1;  //first line -> number of available metals.
        (...)
```

Comment: `argv[1] != "file.txt"` Will never be false.

Comment: You're using C++?
Please, just convert the arguments directly to std::string_view or std::string, and always ensure you actually have the argument passed you are checking (calling with no arguments would be out-of-range access, for example).
Better yet, use a good library that handles command line interfacing :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare two C strings instead of comparing addresses where they are stored.

That is write

```
#include <cstring>

//...

if( strcmp( argv[1], "file.txt" ) != 0 ){
```

Otherwise in this if statement

```
if(argv[1] != "file.txt"){
```

there are compared two pointers: `argv[1]` and the pointer to the first character of the string literal `"file.txt"`.

As the strings occupy different extents of memory the condition of the if statement will always evaluate to true.